# parsing url for specific param value

Tags: regex

im looking to use a regular expression to parse a URL to get a specific section of the url and nothing if I cannot find the pattern.
A url example is

`/te/file/value/jifle?uil=testing-cdas-feaw:jilk:&jklfe=https://value-value.jifels/temp.html/topic?id=`**e997aad4-92e0-j30e-a3c8-jfkaliejs5**`#c452fds-634d-f424fds-cdsa&bf_action=jildape`

I wish to get the bolded text in it.

Currently im using the regex "`d=([^#]*)`" but the problem is im also running across urls of this pattern:
and im getting the bold section of it

`/te/file/value/jifle?uil=testing-cdas-feaw:jilk:&jklfe=https://value-value.jifels/temp.html/topic?id=`**e997aad4-92e0-j30e-a3c8-jfkaliejs5&bf_action=jildape**

I would prefer it have no matches of this url because it doesnt contain the #

Comment: Is there a specific language you are writing the regex for?

Answer (score 0):

Regexes are not a magic tool that you should always use just because the problem involves a string.  In this case, your language probably has a tool to break apart URLs for you.  In PHP, this is `parse_url()`.  In Perl, it's the URI::URL module.

You should almost always prefer an existing, well-tested solution to a common problem like this rather than writing your own.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to match the value of the id parameter, but only if it has a trailing section containing a '#' symbol (without matching the '#' or what's after it)?

Not knowing the specifics of what style of regexes you're using, how about something like:

```
id=([^#&]*)#
```

Answer (score 0):

```
regex = "id=([\\w-])+?#"
```

This will grab everything that is character class[a-zA-Z_0-9-] between 'id=' and '#' assuming everything between 'id=' and '#' is in that character class(i.e. if an '&' is in there, the regex will fail).

```
id=
```

-Self explanatory, this looks for the exact match of 'id='

```
([\\w-])
```

-This defines and character class and groups it. The \w is an escaped \w. '\w' is a predefined character class from java that is equal to [a-zA-Z_0-9]. I added '-' to this class because of the assumed pattern from your examples.

```
+?
```

-This is a reluctant quantifier that looks for the shortest possible match of the regex.

```
#
```

-The end of the regex, the last character we are looking for to match the pattern.

---

If you are looking to grab every character between 'id=' and the first '#' following it, the following will work and it uses the same logic as above, but replaces the character class `[\\w-]` with `.`, which matches anything.

```
regex = "id=(.+?)#"
```